# C# Linq to Entities Custom query to create one field in parent entity that contains a collection of child entities for binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, hierarchy, entities

I am trying to create a binding source for a gridview that contains the datasource for a child gridview.  I have attempted it in the following way:

I have 3 tables:
Patients: id(PK), fname, fname
Study: id(FK),study_id(PK),treatment_site,treatment_type,physician,dosimetrist
Study_Status:study_id(PK,FK),hasContours,hasPlan,isReady

I have the following model:

```
public class myPatient
{
     public string fname { get; set; }
     public string lname { get; set; }
     public bool hascontours { get; set; }
     public bool hasplan { get; set; }
     public bool isready { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<editPatient> epr{ get; set; }
}

public class editPatient
{
     public string fname { get; set; }
     public string lname { get; set; }
     public string txsite { get; set; }
     public string txtype { get; set; }
     public string physician { get; set; }
     public string dosimetrist { get; set; }
}

public class myPatientList : List<myPatient>
{
    public myPatientsList()
    {
        AddRange(getMyPatients().ToList());
    }

    public IEnumerable<myPatient> getMyPatients()
    {
        Connection plan_trackerEM = new Connection();
        return from np in plan_trackerEM.patients
               join ns in plan_trackerEM.studies on np.ID equals ns.Id
               join nss in plan_trackerEM.study_status on ns.study_id equals nss.study_id
               where ns.dosimetrist == App.userClass.user_id || ns.physician == App.userClass.user_id)
               select new myPatient()
               {
                   fname = np.fname,
                   lname = np.lname,
                   hascontours = nss.hasContours,
                   hasplan = nss.hasPlan,
                   isready = nss.isReady,
                   epr = getEditPatients(ns.study_id).ToList()
               };

    }

    public IEnumerable<editPatient> getEditPatients(long study_id)
    {
        Connection plan_trackerEM = new Connection();
        return from np in plan_trackerEM.patients
               join ns in plan_trackerEM.studies on np.ID equals ns.Id
               where ns.study_id == study_id
               select new editPatient()
               {
                   fname = np.fname,
                   lname = np.lname,
                   txsite = ns.treatment_site,
                   txtype = ns.treatment_type,
                   physician = ns.physician,
                   dosimetrist = ns.dosimetrist
               };

    }
}
```

Then I bind the data using XML

```
<local:myPatientsList x:Key="mPL"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MP" Source="{StaticResource mPL}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="EP" Source="{Binding epr, Source={StaticResource MP}}"/>
```

This errors out with: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Plan_Tracker.editPatient] ToList[editPatient](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Plan_Tracker.editPatient])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Any pointers on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.  The data that will be stored in the field "epr" will need to be editable by the user.

**EDIT 2013-05-21** 
Ok, I might be getting closer with a very odd work around.
I removed 
    epr = getEditPatients(ns.study_id).ToList() 
from the query results and then added after the query results:

```
List<mypatientResults> new_tmp_mp = new List<mypatientResults>();

foreach (mypatientResults tmp_mp in _mp)
{
    tmp_mp.epr = getEditPatients(tmp_mp.sid).ToList();
    new_tmp_mp.Add(tmp_mp);    
}
return new_tmp_mp;
```

This is now runnign without error, but I have not been successful (YET) in using epr as a datasource.  I have added it as a column to a datagrid for debugging and it does report it as a System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Plan_Tracker.editpatientResults], but that could be from declaring the variable and not because of the data.

I am still overmy head here and could use help figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure the reasoning, possible that Linq does not like the tree-like structure?!? regardless the edited text above was the solution.  I was able to successfully create custom hierarchy and show it in a parent/child gridview.